# CollectionCell displays wrong image?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `TableView` with cells, and one cell is holding a `CollectionView`.

Inside the CollectionView, I have cells with UIImageViews.

If I add new elements to the datasource while the `CollectionView is visible` then it works fine.

But if I scroll down in the TableView, add the new elements then scroll up, then even though it adds the new cells, they are displaying the wrong image.

Video:  https://youtu.be/QwvMv2xaaAI

---

Code:

**MainViewController**(Not the whole)

```
func addNewPhotos(newPhotosArray: [Photo]){
    var collectionViewInserts : [IndexPath] = []
    for (i in 0...newPhotosArray.count) {

        // I add the new photos to the datasource
        PhotosStore.shared.photos.insert(newPhotosArray[i], at: 0)
        // Then save the indexPath what needs to be inserted
        collectionViewInserts.insert(IndexPath(row: i, section: 0), at: 0)
    }

    if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as? PhotosCell {
        cell.photosCollectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            cell.photosCollectionView.insertItems(at: collectionViewInserts)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension MainViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return PhotosStore.shared.photos.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotoCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoCell

        cell.photoImageView.downloadedFrom(link: (appSettings.url + "/resources/img/wp/prev/" + PhotosStore.shared.photos[indexPath.item].fileName))

        return cell
    }
}
```

**PhotosCell:**

```
import UIKit

class PhotosCell : UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var photosCollectionView : UICollectionView!

}

extension PhotosCell {

    func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate<D: UICollectionViewDataSource & UICollectionViewDelegate>(_ dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int) {

        // IF I PLACE A .reloadData() HERE, THEN IT WORKS BUT THEN THE CELL FLICKERS/JUMPS WHEN APPEARING ON SCREEN

        let itemSize = 70

        photosCollectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
        photosCollectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.horizontal
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemSize, height: itemSize)
        photosCollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)

        photosCollectionView.tag = row
        photosCollectionView.setContentOffset(photosCollectionView.contentOffset, animated:false) // Stops collection view if it was scrolling.
        photosCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

    var collectionViewOffset: CGFloat {
        set { photosCollectionView.contentOffset.x = newValue }
        get { return photosCollectionView.contentOffset.x }
    }
}
```

What do I wrong? I do update the datasource correctly, I do perform batch updates on the collection view to insert the correct cells..

> **Updated details:**

**MainViewController:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Photos on top
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PhotosCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotosCell
            cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)
            cell.collectionViewOffset = storedPhotosCollectionViewOffset[indexPath.row] ?? 0
            return cell
        }
   ... other cells ...
}
```

**Extension to download images:** (I'm sure that's not the problem but just in case)

```
extension UIImageView {
    func downloadedFrom(url: URL, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {

        image = nil

        if let cachedImage = ImageCache.shared.loadCachedImage(url: url) {
            image = cachedImage
            return
        }

        contentMode = mode
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.image = UIImage(named: "imageMissing")
                    }
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.image = image
                    ImageCache.shared.cacheImage(image: image, url: url)
                }
            }.resume()
    }
    func downloadedFrom(link: String, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
            guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
             return downloadedFrom(url: url, contentMode: mode)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post cellForRowAt of the tableView

Comment: @Sh_Khan added!

Answer (score 1):

First in `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.photosCollectionView.reloadData()
return cell
```

Second you have to note that the image is downloaded ( consider a dummy image for the imageView or set a background to it ) every scroll so use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: I tried that, It works but flickers the cells, therefore I was thinking it wasn't the solution (video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjZy_dPfhYw)
Oh, thank you, but I am caching the images, included the code in the thread